# How to add a centered systeme inside an unnumbered list (itemize)

Tags: equations, itemize, systeme

I am trying to obtain this:

[image]

I use `itemize` and `\systeme`

```
\begin{itemize}
  \item \[
  \systeme*{3 - 4x > 5,6 + 9x \leq 1}
  \]
  \item \[
  \systeme*{3x -6 > 2x,2x - 6 > 5x}
  \]
\end{itemize}
```

But I end up with:

[image]

I would like that the bullet from the unordered list to be centered in the `\systeme`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I add my answer using the enviroment cases instead of `systeme` package with the simple common package `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item $\mathrel{\mkern-15mu}\begin{cases}
3 - 4x > 5&\\
6 + 9x \leq 1
\end{cases}$
\item $\mathrel{\mkern-15mu}\begin{cases}
3x -6 > 2x&\\
2x - 6 > 5x
\end{cases}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to approach the point (bullet) near the system symbol you can increase the value `15mu` (always with the minus sign) and, from the output, you see what is your preferred distance.

Comment: Thank you @Sebastiano

Comment: @CristiGhinea Welcome to the TeX.SE. My best regards.

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there! All you need to change is to replace the display-math setting with an inline-math setting, i.e., replace the `\[ ... \]` wrapper with `$ ... $`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item $\systeme*{3 - 4x > 5,6 + 9x \leq 1}$
  \item $\systeme*{3x -6 > 2x,2x - 6 > 5x}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two solutions for horizontally and vertically centred systems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.2pt}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \makebox[\linewidth]{$ \systeme*{3 - 4x > 5,6 + 9x \leq 1} $}
  \item \hfill $ \systeme*{3x -6 > 2x,2x - 6 > 5x} $\hfill\null
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]